# PHP MySQL Image table

Tags: php, html, mysql

what is the best way to construct an image table in which each user has his own photo album. what I did so far is create a user table with id, username, name etc. fields. I am confused how to construct the image table which will contain all the photos of the users.

any suggestions

Comment: as a `byte[]` if it is possible. Then you just take the file stream and place it in a variable. After that you can use inside the image tag src attribute base 64 encoding. so that way your server script doesnt have to do any processing! This [link](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Storing-Images-in-MySQL-with-PHP.html) may help you out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE user_images (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT REFERENCES user (id),
    image_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    image_data BLOB
);
```